# Resolved: getSymbols in quantmod throwing out: Error in new.session() : Could not establish session after 5 attempts

Tags: r, quantmod

I did a fresh install on a new machine of Microsoft OpenR and RStudio. I installed the latest packages of everything. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in new.session() : Could not establish session after 5 attempts.
```

I've tried updating, rebooting my machine, but it's a no-go. I saw that this was a problem in April but that was fixed quickly. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can troubleshoot the problem? I am using code I have used for years so it's not a syntax issue.

Here is what I am doing:

```
symbols <-c("AOR", "AOM")
getSymbols(symbols, src = "yahoo", auto.assign=T)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't replicate your issue, unless I disconnect my wifi. Are you sure your new machine has the correct firewall settings to be able to download data from yahoo?

Comment: Hi Phiver, Thank you for taking a look. I resolved the issue yesterday. The problem was that I didn't have the latest version of Quanmod on my machine. Even though it was a new install, and I used the update function in RStudio, the version installed was v4.17. I found out from Joshua (Quantmod maintainer), that the v4.20 release corrected the problem. I downloaded it from CRAN and manually installed it. I've never done that before, so I learned something new and useful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was due to using an outdated version, the issue is resolved in current versions of the package